# Issue updating checkboxes in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My app has two buttons, each triggering a single 'All' checkbox and a group of checkboxes with column values from the `starwars` dataset (when the 'All' box is checked/unchecked, all the boxes are selected/unselected).

Using built-in Shiny widgets, everything works as expected until I click a button again, which resets the boxes to their default states, although I stored the selected values in a reactive object.

How could I keep the selected boxes values when I click the button a second time?

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data <- starwars %>% head(20)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("species", "Species"),
    actionButton("homeworld", "Home World"),
    uiOutput("checkboxes"),
    br(), br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    ### Store the checkboxes values
    # --- Store the 'All' checkbox value to remember when clicking the button again
    selectionAll <- reactiveValues(species = NULL, homewrold = NULL)
    
    observe({
        selectionAll$species <- input$checkbox_species_all
        selectionAll$homeworld <- input$checkbox_homeworld_all
    })
    
    # --- Store the other checkboxes values to remember when clicking the button again
    selection <- reactiveValues(species = NULL, homeworld = NULL)
    
    observe({
        selection$species <- input$checkbox_species
        selection$homeworld <- input$checkbox_homeworld
    })
    
    ### Species values
    # --- Possible 'species' values
    values_species <- data$species %>% unique() %>% sort()
    
    observeEvent(input$species, {
        # --- On button click, display the 'All' and 'species' checkboxes (all selected)
        output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
            div(
                checkboxInput(inputId = "checkbox_species_all",
                              label = "All",
                              value = T),
                                 
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkbox_species",
                                   label = NULL,
                                   choices = values_species,
                                   selected = values_species)
            )
        })
        
        # --- When clicking the button again, reinstate the values selected before
        updateCheckboxInput(session,
                            inputId = "checkbox_species_all",
                            value = selectionAll$species)
        
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                 inputId = "checkbox_species",
                                 selected = try({if(selectionAll$species){selection$species}else{c("")}}, silent = T))
    })

    # --- When checking the 'All' box, select all
    observeEvent(input$checkbox_species_all, {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                 inputId = "checkbox_species",
                                 selected = try({if(input$checkbox_species_all){values_species}else{c("")}}, silent = T))
    })
    
    
    ### Home worlds values
    # --- Possible 'homeworld' values
    values_homeworld <- data$homeworld %>% unique() %>% sort()
    
    observeEvent(input$homeworld, {
        # --- On button click, display the 'All' and 'homeworld' checkboxes (all selected)
        output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
            div(
                checkboxInput(inputId = "checkbox_homeworld_all",
                              label = "All",
                              value = T),
                
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkbox_homeworld",
                                   label = NULL,
                                   choices = values_homeworld,
                                   selected = values_homeworld)
            )
        })
        
        # --- When clicking the button again, reinstate the values selected before
        updateCheckboxInput(session,
                            inputId = "checkbox_homeworld_all",
                            value = selectionAll$homeworld)
        
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                 inputId = "checkbox_homeworld",
                                 selected = try({if(selectionAll$homeworld){selection$homeworld}else{c("")}}, silent = T))
    })

    # --- When checking the 'All' box, select all
    observeEvent(input$checkbox_homeworld_all, {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                 inputId = "checkbox_homeworld",
                                 selected = try({if(input$checkbox_homeworld_all){values_homeworld}else{c("")}}, silent = T))
    })
    
    ### Checking the values selected
    output$check <- renderPrint({
        cat("selection$species: \n")
        print(selection$species)
        cat("\n-----------------\n\n")
        cat("selection$homeworld: \n")
        print(selection$homeworld)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not sure to understand. Perhaps you can store the observer in a variable: `obs <- observe({......` and call `obs$destroy()` when you want it to not observe anymore. Also you might be interested in `shinyjs::reset`.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent. Thanks for your help ! Actually I am trying to do the opposite of resetting the boxes. Suppose the following sequence of events: (1) click 'Species' button; (2) select whatever species value(s); (3) click 'Home World' button; (4) select whatever homeworld value(s); (5) click 'Species' button again: the previous selection of values has been reset ! At step (5), the first selection of species made at step (2) should appear (not all boxes checked).